# Strapi: How to upload image and link it to Model?

Tags: javascript, react-native, strapi

Say I have a model `Restaurant`, and I want to upload an image and link it to the model.
From [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#usage) this should happen in two steps:

1. Create new entity
2. Upload and link image

Currently, after I create the entity and try to do step 2 it fails.
Note: Image is obtained from [React-Native image picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker)

Here is what I am doing:

```
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('files', image.uri);
      data.append('refId', id);
      data.append('ref', 'Restaurants');
      data.append('field', 'Logo');
```

What I see is that the image is not uploaded. Furthermore, debugging from Strapi side, I see the request with all these data as `fields`.

I am using `FormData` as mentioned in the documentation, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out that I need to add some extra information to the `files` key so that `FormData` recongnize it as a file and Strapi can handle file upload.
Here is what works:

```
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('files', {
        uri: logo.uri,
        name: `test.jpg`,
        type: 'multipart/form-data'
      });
      data.append('refId', id);
      data.append('ref', 'Restaurants');
      data.append('field', 'Logo');
```

What matters really is the `type: 'multipart/form-data`.

One more remark, in the [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#usage), there is another key called `source`. I didn't use it and it seems not to affect anything. Note sure if it needed.

Comment: Hey, Hear  id `data.append('refId', id);`  mean restaurant id ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yes it is

Comment: Hi, do you have curl example?

Comment: Found the way through trial and error: `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:1337/model' \
--form 'data={"model_name": "Model Name"}' \
--form 'files.image=@image.png'`